# How to run cron jobs in IST in hostinger

Tags: laravel, cron

I created a  cron job for my laravel application in hostinger , but my server is UTC , i want to run it in IST .

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{

        $schedule->command('websockets:clean')->daily();
        //toggle store status
        $schedule->command("store:toggle")->everyMinute();
        //toggle product status
        $schedule->command("product:toggle")->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command("driver:isbusy")->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command("tempdata:dump")->daily();
}
```

this is from kernel.php

Comment: How did you configure your cron in the server? Using Crontab or using Laravel's `php artisan schedule:run` command?

Comment: php artisan schedule:run using this command

Answer (score 1):

You can add a global timezone in your `Kernel.php` or mention the timezone for a specific scheduled task.

- Globally

```
use DateTimeZone;
 
// add this function in your app/Console/Kernel.php
protected function scheduleTimezone(): DateTimeZone|string|null
{
    return 'Asia/Kolkata';
}
```

- Individual task

```
$schedule->command('websockets:clean')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')->daily();
```

More about scheduling according to timezone in Laravel -> https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#timezones

Comment: protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        $schedule->command('websockets:clean')->daily()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');;
        //toggle store status
        $schedule->command("store:toggle")->everyMinute()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');;
        //toggle product status
        $schedule->command("product:toggle")->everyMinute()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');;
        $schedule->command("driver:isbusy")->everyMinute()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');;
        $schedule->command("tempdata:dump")->daily()->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');;
  }
i added these to my code

Comment: Is it working according to IST?

Comment: as i just commented for product toggle , others are  working fine